# How to search for occurrence of two strings using AND in a line

Tags: string, search, awk, grep

I want to search for the occurrence of multiple strings in each line and print the lines which have the two strings occurred. Find occurrence of a single  string is trivial using grep. However, if I want to test the ocurrence of `AB+CD` and `nonCD` at the **SAME LINE** without considering their order (because using `AB+CD.*nonCD` will always assume the AB+CD occurrence before `nonCD` which is unsuitable for my case. This is a sample of the file content:

```
google.com,9,AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD
youtube.com,9,AB+CD,AB+CD
facebook.com,20,nonCD
```

If I try: `grep -E 'AB+CD|nonCD' file1.txt` it prints:

```
google.com,9,AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD
facebook.com,20,nonCD
```

What I want is the occurrence of `AB+CD` AND `nonCD` **in the same line togather** without considering their order nor how many times they occurred.

Comment: Also, `grep -P '^(?=.*AB+CD)(?=.*nonCD)' file1.txt`

Comment: Using ERE `grep -E 'AB\+CD.*nonCD file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I guess the `+` needs to be escaped, ain't it?

Comment: @Inian If the `+` is a literal `+` and not a quantifier, yes, it should be escaped in a PCRE pattern.

Comment: @Inian I am not getting what you mean by `\`. The `+` is part of the string. Not mathematical plus. My string is `AB+CD`. In this case, shall I use `\+`

Comment: @Inian when I use `AB\+CD` it does not find the string `AB+CD`. When I remove `\`. So `\` is not required if I want the string eaxactly `AB+CD` (not arithmatic plus).